# where does variables of shared library stored when linked to a application

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries

Where do the variables used in shared library gets stored. when used with an application. shared library uses same application sections(data/stack). or will they have seperate sections.

Answer (score 0):

Only the section that contains the code is shared. Variables are not shared between processes.

Comment: That is wrong. `const` qualified are typically and others might be, too, until modified on a modern OS.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to share variables between two processes is if they both have access to a shared memory page - see [mmap](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) and `MAP_SHARED`. Otherwise, they're in the calling process's memory space, and out-of-reach or out-of-scope of other processes.

Answer (score 0):

Static libraries: Library of object code which is linked with, and becomes part of the application.

Dynamically linked shared object libraries: The shared objects are not included into the executable component but are tied to the execution.